Draw Small Regular Polygons
I'd like to use tikz to draw regular polygons that are too small for shapes.geometric. My goal is to have them in-line with the text:

But when I try to write a tikzset to so I can quickly and easily draw any given polygon, I get an error ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
I think the issue is that I perform calculations on the argument of the tikzset inside the set that defines a for loop. But I don't know how get TeX to recognize the argument as numeric.
Here's my working code for the text above:
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newdimen\R
\R=0.1cm
foo
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Indicate the boundary of the regular polygons

    \draw[xshift=2.5\R] (0:\R) \foreach \x in {90,180,...,359} {
            -- (\x:\R)
        } -- cycle (90:\R) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
baz 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Indicate the boundary of the regular polygons

    \draw[xshift=2.5\R] (0:\R) \foreach \x in {72,144,...,360} {
            -- (\x:\R)
        } -- cycle (90:\R) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

(I got the code for the polygons here.)
And the broken code:
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
pics/Polygon/.style n args ={2}{%
background code = {
    \draw[xshift=2.5*#2] (0:#2) \foreach \x in {360/#1,2*360/#1,...,360} {
            -- (\x:#2)
        } -- cycle (360/3:#2);
    }
}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) pic {Polygon={5}{0.8cm}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

From playing around with different options, I know the problem is that 360/#1 and 2*360/#1 don't work well in set used to define the for loop.

Why do you add a coordinate after the cycle? That's just a move-to to that point.


regular polygons that are too small for shapes.geometric

Set inner sep to zero to control their size through minimum size (which sets the radius).
Though, if you don't need it to be a node, there's no need to use the shape. It can be easily achieved with a sharp cycle plot which has a built-in loop.
As the drawing is so simple, I've also added a PGF version.
Code
\documentclass[varwidth, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\newcommand*\tikzPolygonShape[3][]{%
  \tikz[#1]
    \node[draw, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size={2*(#3)}, rotate=90-180/(#2),
      shape=regular polygon, regular polygon sides={#2}]{};}

\newcommand*\tikzPolygonPlot[3][]{%
  \tikz[#1]
    \draw plot[sharp cycle, samples at={1, ..., #2}] ({\x*360/(#2)}:{#3});}

\newcommand*\tikzPolygonPGF[2]{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}
    \pgfplotfunction{\x}{1, ..., #1}{\pgfpointpolar{\x*360/(#1)}{#2}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  \end{pgfpicture}}

\pgfset{foreach/eval col/.style={evaluate={\c=(\Sides00-300)/7;}}}

\begin{document}
foo \tikzPolygonShape{4}{.3em} baz \tikzPolygonShape{5}{.3em} --%
\foreach[eval col] \Sides in {3, ..., 10}{
  \tikzPolygonShape[red!\c!blue]{\Sides}{.3em}}

foo \tikzPolygonPlot{4}{.3em} baz \tikzPolygonPlot{5}{.3em} --%
\foreach[eval col] \Sides in {3, ..., 10}{
  \tikzPolygonPlot[red!\c!blue]{\Sides}{.3em}}

foo \tikzPolygonPGF{4}{.3em} baz \tikzPolygonPGF{5}{.3em} --%
\foreach[eval col] \Sides in {3, ..., 10}{
  \color{red!\c!blue}\tikzPolygonPGF{\Sides}{.3em}}
\end{document}

Output


One of a nice suggestion with character height and width

\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
pics/Polygon/.style n args ={2}{%
background code = {
    \draw[xshift=2.5*#2] (0:#2) \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \angle using \x*360/#1] in {1,2,...,#1} {-- (\angle:#2)} -- cycle ;
    }
}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) pic {Polygon={5}{0.8cm}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



You just need to add parse = true to \foreach, \foreach[parse = true] ....
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
pics/Polygon/.style n args ={2}{%
background code = {
    \draw[xshift=2.5*#2] (0:#2) \foreach[parse = true] \x in {360/#1,2*360/#1,...,360} {
            -- (\x:#2)
        } -- cycle (360/3:#2);
    }
}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) pic {Polygon={5}{0.8cm}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


You can also do this neatly with lualatex + luamplib using the Metapost support.

Compile this with lualatex.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\newcommand\poly[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbin{\vcenter{\begin{mplibcode}beginfig(0); 
  draw for i=1 upto #1: 3 dir (360 / #1 * (i-1)) -- endfor cycle;
endfig;\end{mplibcode}}}}}
\begin{document}

foo \poly{4} baz \poly{5}. As a math binary:  \(5 \poly{3} 7\).

\end{document}


\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    pics/Polygon/.style n args={2}{background code={
        \draw (0:#2) \foreach \x in {2,...,#1} {-- (-360/#1+360*\x/#1:#2)} -- cycle;
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) pic {Polygon={5}{0.8cm}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



If you like PS-Tricks, then try with the below:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-poly}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-1,-1)(1,1)
\PstPolygon[PstPicture=false]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}


